# how to set shot variable object C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

if have checkbox name 1-9 below

```
checkbox_1 = true
checkbox_2 = true
.....
checkbox_9 = true
```

how can revise object shot name that below

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    checkbox + "something" + i + "checked" = true
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want? SHOT variable?? Read about string.Format()

Comment: what does `shot` means? you want to set all checkbox at once by the loop?

Comment: You need to use Page.Controls to get all the controls on the page. Then loop them and check if the control is a checkbox. If it is, set the `Checked` property to true. Search online for how to loop and find controls in asp.net. You can also store all the checkboxes in an array and loop them and set their checked property.

Comment: If the checkboxes are on the page you can do this: `CheckBox found = FindControl" + i) as CheckBox; found.Checked = true;`. If it's not within the page then call `FindControl` on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If have checkbox 9 objects. I need to loop update through all checkboxes
   usually use `checkbox1.checked = true --> checkbox9.checked = true`
   I need to use loop for update checkbox such as

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
       checkbox +  i + ".checked" = true
    }
```

How to do? thank you

Comment: You have posted an answer to your own question but you must likely didn't mean to. No you cannot check the checkboxes like that. Please delete this answer and add this information to your question above.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum but Questions and Answers. You should not "continue the conversation" but edit your question to include further details (and then delete this "answer")

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CheckBox[] checkbox = new CheckBox[4];
checkbox[0] = checkBox_1;
checkbox[1] = checkBox_2;
checkbox[2] = checkBox_3;
checkbox[3] = checkBox_4;
for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
{
   checkbox[i].Checked=true;
}
```

Comment: dear Dhanushka Dayawansha  can you remove       
            checkbox[0] = checkBox_1;
            checkbox[1] = checkBox_2;
            checkbox[2] = checkBox_3;
            checkbox[3] = checkBox_4;  left then                                           
      CheckBox[] checkbox = new CheckBox[4];                                                      
        for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
            {
               checkbox[i].Checked=true;

            }

Comment: did you try my answer?